# Que puedo hacer cuando me sale un aviso de un indice fuera de intervalo?

Tags: c#

El índice estaba fuera del intervalo. Debe ser un valor no negativo e inferior al tamaño de la colección.

este es el mensaje que sale cuando mi programa ya esta ejecutando un proceso de operacion sencilla como una suma, resta o multiplicacion.

aqui mi codigo

```
dgview_matrices.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = MatrizResultadosum[i, j].ToString();
```

intento hacer un programa de matrices usando un respectivo datagridview como lo ven el codigo por que intento generar en dgv el resultado de la operacion correspondiente en este caso es una suma y me comienza a saltar ese mensaje

Comment: Ese mensaje te está indicando que alguno de los índices (`i` o `j`) es mayor que el número de filas o columnas. Para darte una respuesta mas ajustada, deberías mostrar tu bucle y describir cuantas filas y columnas tiene tu `DataGridView`.

Comment: podrias poner algo mas del contexto de esa linea del codigo? porque esta claro que el problema se presenta con los valores que toma `i` y `j` pero ademas como estas creando las nuevas Rows en el datagridview ? porque magicamente no se crean y sino lo haces no vas a poder acceder a estas usando su index